# .NET Core: convert geometry into GeoJson in API

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, postgis

I have a geometry type in postGis like this:

[image]

In .NET Core, I have these services:

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;    
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());   
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NetTopologySuite.IO.Converters.GeoJsonConverterFactory());     
          
    });
```

Now in my controller, I have this query:

```
var result = await _context.Provinces
                           .AsQueryable()
                           .GroupBy(s => s.countryName)
                           .ToListAsync();

return Ok(result);
```

The result is more than 18 mb in size, and this is too much.

How can I send this geometry data to front as an API? Is it possible to convert it to GeoJson and then send to the frontend?